# PHP get_headers not working?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I want to get headers of website but get_headers return nothing 
This is my code

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

print_r(get_headers($url));
?>
```

For your information my web hosting provider is network solution 
Does the problem from my code or from the web hosting provider ?
And what's the solution to get the headers of one website ?

Comment: It can be disabled on the server. Can you put on error_reporting and see if you get any warnings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If get_headers is disabled then you can also use cURL instead.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(    
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true));

$header = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

print_r($header);
```

Comment: it's working but i want receive `[Server] => Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)` like this because i want to know the OS of the server

Comment: @user3609057 you do know that some servers block this kind of information for security reasons, right?

Comment: @CreativeMind yes of course but before on same website i get headers but when i changed to network solution it just stop :/ any solution ?

Comment: @CreativeMind ah yeah the problem was from the website any way thank you Best Answer

Comment: @user3609057 before you try any programmatic way, first check if the server you are testing this on gives this info at all, by using tools like: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ for Firefox

Comment: but what if there is no cURL? Like in PHP4