# get_headers() not returning Content-Length element

Tags: php, get-headers

Function `get_headers()` does not give an array with the same indexes when I make a change in domain. When and why does this occur?

I want `Content-Length` value for hundreds of domains. What changes do I need to make?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.ecomexpomelbourne.com.au/sponsors/';
echo "<pre>";
$domain_data[] = array();
$domain_data = get_headers( $url, 1 );
print_r($domain_data);
echo $domain_data['Last-Modified'];
?>
```

When used for current page url I get Content-Length index
[image]

Comment: Probably something to do with your server configuration.

Comment: Your server don't send Content-Length so there is nothing to get

Comment: There is no such header... https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/4rCuvc

Comment: @PeeHaa When i use get_headers for this web page i get the result as i have edited my question.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the domain you are trying to get...

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes not the domain, However how does that change? its a webpage after all! Please Explain I did not get

Comment: If the server doesn't send the header there is absolutely nothing you can do besides doing an actual request and calculating the length yourself. You can show us the headers of other sites, but that has nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: Please check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844680/php-get-headers-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844680/php-get-headers-not-working) I think this can be help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the server just does not send the `Content-length` header, and you should expect and treat properly such cases, as there are such provisions described in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13).

In some situations, when the page is dynamically generated (with PHP or other language), the length of the body is not known yet at the stage of the sending of headers, so there is no way for the server to generate proper `Content-length` header in advance. But there are also [cases when the `Content-length` header is explicitly forbidden to be sent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).

Comment: Yes Content-Length I got for one page.

Comment: If I dont get is there no other way by which I can get this?

Comment: You can do it by using [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and passing an `URL` to it. But also mind that it will create some network overhead as it is going to fetch the entire page to get its length.

Comment: filesize() when used gives an error `Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://www.ecomexpomelbourne.com.au/sponsors/ in D:\xampp`

Comment: @KouberSaparev, _You can do it by using filesize()_ - only if `http://` wrapper [is supported](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)

Comment: @Penny, look at the second comment under the function description for filesize() in the link I gave you above.

Comment: @KouberSaparev Thanks it gave me some value. But it shows lot of difference when compared with value in firebug tool!

Answer (score 0):

PWS is hopelessly outdated, use IIS instead. I'm not sure that PWS allows to configure response headers and I can't find any docs. This is what it sends now:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 09 Dec 2014 09:46:13 GMT
Expires:Mon, 08 Dec 2014 09:46:13 GMT
Server:PWS/8.1.20.5
Set-Cookie:www.ecomexpomelbourne.com.au_trackingData=; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-Px:nc h0-s4.p1-hyd ( h0-s2.p6-lhr), nc h0-s2.p6-lhr ( origin)
```

there is no Content-length