# checking if youtube thumbnail exists

Tags: php, youtube

How to know if youtube thumbnail with max resolution exists without using Google API?

For instance, video with code doesn't have maxresolution. If we open URL: `http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/4rlR7EncGD0/maxresdefault.jpg` we can see grey rectangle, that means no thumbnail, right?

The code I have, just checks if file exists. If file exists, it is showed within website. Unfourtunately this doesn't work for those "grey rectangles".

Answer (score 4):

I'am using this:

```
        $item = '4rlR7EncGD0';
        $MaxResURL = 'https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'.$item.'/maxresdefault.jpg';
        //print $MaxResURL;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(    
        CURLOPT_URL => $MaxResURL,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => true));

        $header = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);

        //var_dump($header);        

        //If maxres image exists do something with it.
        if (strpos($header[0], '200') !== false) {    
            print $MaxResURL;
        }else{
            print 'Some Other IMG';
        }
```

This checks the headers  using curl.  And if it is good '200' prints the url, of course you can show the image or what you specifically need to do, I use this to add facebook and twitter metatags.

I used code from this answers:

[How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php)  To check for the 200 on the headers

And

[PHP get_headers not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844680/php-get-headers-not-working) To get the headers witch curl because I'm using wordpress and for some reason get_headers() was not working.

I'm not an expert and I do not know if this is the best aproach to resolve this issue but this code is working for me, hope it helps.